# Are we still working on the WEB platform primitives with Polymer 2.x?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

### Developer costs

> Developer costs come in the form of complexity and lock-in.
>
> Over time, the stacks we’ve built on top of the platform have pushed web development further and further from the simplicity of view-source and shift-refresh, to a place where every project begins with an overwhelming sea of choices.
>
> And when we rely on libraries and frameworks for even our most basic needs, we end up writing code that depends on opinionated abstractions rather than universal platform primitives. Because it’s expensive to migrate from one abstraction to another, these dependencies limit our future choices and make our code costlier to maintain.

That is from the polymer about page.

Are there too many changes a developer has to make to transition to Polymer 2?
If so, wouldn't Polymer also bucket itself under "abstraction oriented" rather than "platform oriented" ?
A developer will need to change all his previous code to fit into the new abstraction? 
That would contradict the premise

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you read [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/2016-09-09-polymer-2.0.html) blog post carefully you will notice that the transition from 1.x to 2.0 will be as smooth as possible. The amount of code you have to change largely depends on your use of the elements provided by the Polymer team, because these elements are expected not to change at all on the surface.

In addition to that, you don't HAVE to change your code, since Polymer 1.x will likely be supported on all major browsers for the upcoming years.

Cheers,
Stefan